# Действие при выборе двух элементов

Tags: javascript, html, css

Есть вложенный список, не могу понять как сделать так чтобы при выборе по одному элементу из каждого списка перекидывало на другую страницу (именно при выборе двух элементов)

```css
.ben1{
  background-color: green;
}
.ben2{
  background-color: red;
}
a{
  text-decoration: none;
  color: black;
}
ul{
  list-style-type: none;
  margin-top: 5px;
  padding: 0;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 22px;
}
li:hover{
  background-color: cadetblue;
 }
```

```html
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">STERKA</a></li>
      <li><a href="">PENKA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="ben2">
  <ul>
      <li><a href="">REPKA</a></li>
      <li><a href="">KEPKA</a></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```js
var a = 0;
var selected = 0;
function checkIfTwoSelected(classnum){
    if( a == 0 ){
       selected = classnum;
       a = 1;
    }else if(a == 1){
       if(selected != classnum){
           window.location = "http://some.com/somepage";
           a = 0;
       }
    }
}
```

```html
   
<div class="ben1">
  <ul>
      <li><div onclick="checkIfTwoSelected(1)">STERKA</div></li>
      <li><div onclick="checkIfTwoSelected(1)">PENKA</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
<div class="ben2">
  <ul>
      <li><div onclick="checkIfTwoSelected(2)">REPKA</div></li>
      <li><div onclick="checkIfTwoSelected(2)">KEPKA</div></li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Потестил ваш способ, никуда не перекидывает... Пойду тогда сам js изучать

Comment: Протестировал у себя. Перекидывает на заданный урл. В том случае, если выбрано по одному значению из 2х списков

Comment: Спасибо огромное, допустил глупую ошибку, и поэтому не работало!